# Regex to capitalize first letter of word

Tags: regex, angular

I am using

```
value.replace(/\b\w/g, first => first.toLocaleUpperCase())
```

to convert the first letter of word into uppercase,  and it is working fine.
It's being done using pipe in Angular on ngModel input type.

**My problem is** whenever I keep the cursor before the first letter of the word of the mentioned text field and type something, when I type the second letter automatically goes to the end of the word/sentence, interrupting the typing.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="name"                                                      [ngModel]="p.firstName | sentenceCase"                                                       (ngModelChange)="p.firstName=$event"  #firstName="ngModel">

Comment: this is in html component. I am using pipe  named 'sentenceCase'

Comment: p.firstName.replace(/\b\w/g, first => first.toLocaleUpperCase())  is the code which is doing work of capitalizing.

Comment: Okay will you please provide the pipe also ?

Comment: @Ayman ek temsahi... Can we capitalize first letter of sentence for inline elements using css?

Comment: @AnitaMishra, as far as I know it will work.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you should use a pipe to do that, use `CSS` to show the capitalized first letter like this :

```
input {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

and when the user submits the form, modify the data then..